# Setting a CMD variable with multiple escapes

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd

I want to set a Windows CMD variables to a UNIX `date` call, specifically:

```
date '+%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y'
```

It works fine in my cmd window:

```
set STRING=^`date ^'^+^%H:^%M:^%S ^%m/^%d/^%y^'^`

echo %STRING%
date '+%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y'
```

But when I put thin a batch file like try.bat

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set STRING=^`date ^'^+^%H:^%M:^%S ^%m/^%d/^%y^'^`
echo STRING is %STRING%
```

it comes out weird (whether I use delayed expansion or not):

```
>try.bat
STRING is `date '+m/y'`
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape `%` signs with more `%` signs. Also, `'` don't need to be escaped.

```
set string=date '+%%H:%%M:%%S %%m/%%d/%%y'
```